# Define a struct in a midl generated header file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, midl, visual-studio-6

I am in the process of automating the build of a legacy product and have hit a wall...

I have a .idl file that is compiled in VC++ 6.0 using midl to generate a .tlb, .h and .c file that has a manual build step to add:

```
struct StructDef;
```

Just ahead of an MIDL_INTERFACE in the generated .h file.  The rest of the .h file uses the definition, and I cannot compile until this is added.

I am looking for a way to autogenerate the header file with the struct definition (preferred), or at least a way to automate this code adding step through a custom build step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`#pragma midl_echo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367143%28VS.85%29.aspx) instructs MIDL to insert an arbitrary piece of text into the generated header file.  You can use it like this:

```
#pragma midl_echo("struct StructDef;")
```

It appears that the [`cpp_quote`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366765%28VS.85%29.aspx) attribute provides similar functionality.

Alternatively, if you have [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) installed, you may find it simpler (or just preferable) to post-process the header file with [`sed`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) in a custom build step.  That would work as well.